# Installing WINE as a brand new Ubuntu User

Tags: 13.04, wine

I'm trying to get WINE working on Ubuntu 13.04 and after way too much googling and even more hours of bashing my head against the keyboard due to all the failed attempts and dependency issues, I have decided to seek help.  I know nothing about Command Line Syntax aside from the copying and pasting I've found on various searches and frankly don't even know if I've damaged any file structures in the process of my failure.

How do I check if I've  goofed and how I goofed?

This is the error I get from the Software Center.  I get errors in the Terminal too, but wasn't sure which parts were relevant so I thought I'd wait for some input before wall of texting everyone.

```
wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.10ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.17-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but it is a virtual package
```

Comment: Please do wall-of-text us. We can handle that.

Comment: playonlinux makes it a lot easier to manage wineversions, you can install it via sudo apt-get install playonlinux or via the software center!

Answer (score 1):

Try this executing these commands step by step:

> sudo apt-get remove wine
>   sudo apt-get install -f
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install wine1.6
>   sudo apt-get install -f
>   sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -f install

Comment: "sudo apt-get install -f sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" -f install" should be two lines. Add two spaces after "-f" or better: use <pre></pre> tags

Comment: wine1.7 is the newest version. You might use it instead of wine1.6